# The Date type and the Android database

Tags: database, android, sqlite, date

I understand that SQLite stores dates as long integers. When I read rows using the standard method (i.e. using the query() method that reads data into a cursor), the result is a date string that includes the time:

```
2010-05-25 19:52:04
```

If I want a different format, I have to parse the string back into a date - possible, but a bit backwards.

By using a ViewBinder (as suggested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2117565/displaying-dates-in-localized-format-on-android)), I can pretty much do anything I want, but the date is already a string at the time the overridden method executes.

The accepted answer to the above question also suggests that storing dates as longs would help avoid this problem. I don't want to do that, just in case I want to interpret my data with something else than this application. Maybe I want to expose it via a provider.

To make matters worse, a DateFormat instance obtained via

```
android.text.format.DateFormat.getDateFormat(getApplicationContext())
```

cannot parse such a date string that is returned by the cursor. There is actually no static method that can do that - it is a one-way transformation, apparently an oversight.

Is there a way to handle this in the database adapter instead, i.e. controlling the date format that the cursor contains, so that I don't have to change the schema, and don't have to parse the default output back into a Date type?

The answers so far suggest that I should do the output formatting in the database. I don't want to do that for multiple reasons, most notably because I cannot format dates based on the user's locale that way (not easily, that is).

Answer (score 1):

SQLite has a number of built-in [date and time functions.](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)

Comment: I am using android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(), which expects a list of column names. Are you saying that I have to hand-code the query?

Comment: @cdonner, yes, use android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery().

Comment: @cdonner, alternatively (and I can't test it since I don't have an Android platform at hand) I wonder what giving android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query() a column name of "strftime('%Y-%m-%d',date_colname)" would do?

Comment: If I use database functions, I will not get the date formatted in the user's locale (unless I somehow try to build a format string from the locale information). This is not a good idea.

Comment: I have a working solution, i.e. parsing the data string back into a Date variable. It is a bit slow, though.

Comment: The SQLite functions include julianday() which should eliminate the need for parsing.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try this solution:

http://androidcookbook.com/Recipe.seam?recipeId=413

Answer (score 0):

No need to get the date column as string, you should be able to use `getLong(..)` and create a proper `Date` object like this:

```
Date created = new Date(cursor.getLong(createdDateIndex));
```