# Android sqlite date comparison?

Tags: android

How can I compare dates using where statement in sqlite?
I don't know how to write date in timestamp format in DB.
I guess only timestamp format (integer or string in database) I can compare?!

Can someone help me with code for writing date in db (using ContentValues )

I want to use this code for comparison:

```
 Cursor mCursor =
             db.query(true,
               tableName,
               null, 
               KEY_DATETIME + " >= '"+ fromDate +"' and " +
                 KEY_DATETIME + " <= '"+ toDate +"'" , 
               null,
               null, 
               null, 
               null, 
               null);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider storing the date as a long in the SQLite DB which has several advantages. See [my other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2117565/displaying-dates-in-localized-format-on-android) and the accepted answer for more information.