# Displaying localized dates on Android with custom format

Tags: java, android, date-formatting

I used the proposed way to format dates according to the user locale on Android as described in this ticket: [Displaying dates in localized format on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2117565/displaying-dates-in-localized-format-on-android)

However, is there any way to adapt the used format? In my case I wanted to adapt the formatting to show only 2 digits for the year.

```
//displays 4 digits for year
String dateF = android.text.format.DateFormat.getDateFormat(context).format(date);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(2013, 11, 20);
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
String date = df.format(cal.getTime());
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the `SimpleDateFormat`

```
String dateString=null;
SimpleDateFormat originalFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy",Locale.ENGLISH);
try
{
    Date parsedDate  = originalFormat.parse(dateF);
    SimpleDateFormat  targetFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yy",Locale.ENGLISH);
    dateString = targetFormat.format(parsedDate);
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    Log.e(TAG, "error while parsing");
}
Log.d(TAG, "converted date "+dateString);
```